# Will haproxy ever retry a request where the upstream request has timed out waiting for a response?

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to find the exact conditions when haproxy (version 1.4) in layer 7 mode will retry an HTTP request. Its [documentation for `retries`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#4.2-retries) states:

> It is important to understand that this value applies to the number of
>   connection attempts, not full requests. When a connection has effectively
>   been established to a server, there will be no more retry.

Question: **Can I take that as `haproxy` will never retry a request upstream (to backend, that is) when after an upstream connection has been made?** Specifically, I want to be sure that `haproxy` never will reissue something like an `HTTP` `POST` upstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HAProxy will only re-send a request if a backend has not accepted the request.